# vs2019 - Xamarin: loses path settings of "Java Development Kit Location"

Tags: java, android, xamarin, visual-studio-2019

I do a very simple thing.

I go to Tools -> Options -> Xamarin> Android Settings
and I change the "Java Development Kit Location" path.
I press ok.

I compile the project and the option is used correctly.

I go to Tools -> Options -> Xamarin> Android Settings and the path is correct.

I restart VS, I go to Tools -> Options -> Xamarin> Android Settings and the **path is wrong**, it is the previous one.

Visual studio version used:
Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019
Version 16.11.7

happens to someone else?

is it a bug?

thanks

Comment: i switched to VS 2022 and it works fine

Answer (score -3, accepted):

For the error with java development kit location, you could try the stpes below.

1. Install the latest JDK 8 that's available from the Oracle Java SE
   Development Kit 8 Downloads webpage. https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html
2. Follow the instructions in the
   error message to manually point your Visual Studio instance to the
   location of your new JDK.

For the best mobile development experience, we encourage you to update to the latest Visual Studio version to keep up with the latest changes in iOS and Android development.

If you still want to use the old version and could not fix the error with the stpes above. You could try to repair the Visual Studio.

Comment: thanks for your reply.
i updated java to the latest version, but no results.
For now I don't want to use VS2022, I'll try later to repair the Visual Studio.

Comment: i switched to VS 2022 and it works fine

Comment: Not a solution unfortunately. Need OpenJDK, and path is lost everytime I restart VS2019.

Answer (score 2):

I faced a similar issue when updating visual studio 2019 from version **16.3** to **16.11** while working on a react native project, somehow my jdk installation got corrupted during or after installation.
Initiating a repair it from the VS SDK manager did not work and I later found out that my jdk location was changed from:

```
C:\Program Files\Android\jdk\microsoft_dist_openjdk_1.8.0.25
```

to

```
C:\Program Files\Eclipse Foundation\jdk-8.0.302.8-hotspot
```

I updated the **JAVA_HOME** env variable to point to the new location then clean rebuild and everything is back to normal.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for your reply. i haven't tried your solution but i switched to VS 2022 and it works fine